# Reference error in an expandable listview

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create an expandable listview in forms and I am receiving an error "The type or namespace name 'Items' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" I was trying to have the buttons hide or show with a boolean value upon touch.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ExpandableListViewTest
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ListViewType : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

        public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

        public ListViewType()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsVisible = false;

            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                new Items
                {
                    Title = "Sad"
                },
                new Items
                {
                    Title = "Angry"
                },
                new Items
                {
                    Title = "Fearful"
                }
            };
        }
        public void HideOrShowItem(Items item)
        {
            item.IsVisible = true;

            UpdateItems(item);
        }
        private void UpdateProducts(Items item)
        {
            var index = Items.IndexOf(item);
            Items.Remove(item);
            Items.Instert(index, item);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am receiving a type or namespace error that is asking if I am missing an assembly directive or reference"* Could you please give the *exact* error message?

Comment: *Please* edit your question and don't add details as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ObservableCollection` `Items` has the type parameter `string`, but you are trying to create objects of type `Items`, which is not possible for two reasons

- First of all (and this is what the compiler complains about) there *is no type* `Items`, hence you can't create instances of this type
- Second, if the `ObservableCollection` has the type parameter `string` you can't add any items but strings.

You could either add strings to the collection

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                "Sad",
                "Angry",
                "Fearful"
            };
```

*or* you create the type `Item` (renamed it)

```
class Item
{
    Title { get; set; }
}
```

and then create instances of that type:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
            {
                new Item
                {
                    Title = "Sad"
                },
                new Item
                {
                    Title = "Angry"
                },
                new Item
                {
                    Title = "Fearful"
                }
            };
```

Of course you have to change the type of `Items` to `ObservableCollection<Item>`, for the reason stated above (can't add objects of type `Item` to an `ObservableCollection<string>`).